# Accepting multiple http methods?

Tags: java, micronaut

Is there any way to accept multiple http mothods in Micronaut controller? For example, I would like to process GET, POST, and OPTIONS requests in a method. I tried annotated with three annotations `@Get`, `@Post`, and `@Options`, however, only first annotation works and others are ignored.

```
@Controller("/echo")
public class EchoController {

  private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  @Get
  @Post
  @Options
  public HttpResponse<String> process(HttpRequest<?> request) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Headers headers = request.getHeaders();
    return ok(mapper.writeValueAsString(headers.asMap()));
  }
}
```

Is adding separete methods for each HTTP method and annotate them with corresponding annotation the only way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open [issue](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/1422) to allow the HTTP annotations to be repeatable.
It looks like it is planned vor 1.2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the issue doesn't seem like what I am looking for. It's about supporting multiple paths, not multiple http methods.

Comment: @ntalbs That issue is what you're looking for. It would support multiple method annotations, which means multiple methods and paths.

Comment: @JamesKleeh Yes, I could see that the comment about allowing multiple HTTP annotations. Thanks.